# Online tools for scheduling teams round-robin events

Tags: tournament-directors

A solution would allow the creation of pairings, the entering of team results, the viewing of a team ranking table, and ideally allow the listing of an individual ranking table as well.

The best I've found so far is https://tournamentscheduler.net/

However, it seems to have the following limitations:

- It has no respect for colors (so that e.g. it will make Team 1 White in every round)
- It refuses to accept non-integer round results (so you can't say that one team defeated the other 3.5-0.5. You would need to either use match wins as your criterion or else multiply the actual score by 2.

It's also limited in the sense that you can't enter individual results.

Answer (score 3):

What you are really looking for is a pairing program which will perform team round-robin pairing, allow you to enter results and display the results online.

There are two obvious candidates, one expensive and deluxe, and one cheap (free on Linux) which requires a bit more work on your part.

The expensive option is [Swiss Manager](http://swiss-manager.at/). This does everything you could want and more but it costs 150 euros for the full version and 75 euros for the light version (limit 60 players / 11 rounds). This includes a website (chess-results.com) where your tournaments can be viewed.

The cheap / free option is [Vega](https://www.vegachess.com/ns/features). It is free on Linux. On Windows and MacOS it is free for up to 30 players (individual tournament) and 8 teams (team tournament). I paid 50 euros for the full Windows version a few years ago.

Something which is new, which I see for the first time (new since the end of 2019), is that now it also has its own website like Swiss Manager. This is https://www.vegaresult.com/vr/. If you have up to 8 teams or you would run it on Linux then this looks like a very good free solution. Previous versions would generate the HTML for you to copy and paste into your own website. This could still be very useful for more tech-orientated clubs / administrators.