# Tournament Management and Conducting Web App

Tags: software, tournament, online-chess, tournament-directors

Does anyone know about a web based app to conduct and manage chess tournament all online? I have a web server to host but we need to conduct it for our locality with around 300 people participating to enhance our lock-down period.

If it is opensource it is very nice, but if it is free it is more than enough i guess? Any suggestions please?

Comment: This question has been asked several times already in various forms and there are a number of very good answers. Check out - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/468/how-to-organize-a-chess-tournament, https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29603/online-tools-for-scheduling-teams-round-robin-events/29611#29611 and https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/looking-for-online-swiss-pairing-software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already see lichess.org? This website has great tournament functionality. E.g. you can start a swiss tournament and add the participants by making them part of a team. Hence there will be no outsiders present.

Hope this helps :)